# Permission denied error while copying the files to another user directory using WINSCP?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, permissions

I have a few folder in one of my ubuntu machine in the directory `/export/home/` as  -

```
user1
user2
user3
```

Whenever any user login to that machine, it always takes him to that directory as a default. If I am `user1`, and I am logging in to that machine, then after logging, if I do `pwd`, I always see -

`/export/home/user1`

Now what I am supposed to do is, I have opened a winscp on my desktop as `user1` to connect to that machine, and then I need to copy a file from my `desktop` to `user2` folder but whenever I try to open `user2` folder in winscp, it always gives me -

`Permission denied error..`

Is there any way, I can ask `user2` to give me permission (by logging into his account from putty) to copy the files using `winscp` from my desktop to `user2` folder?

Comment: A winscp session is very similar to an interactive shell session.  You'll have the same permissions as if you had SSH'd to the box, so the same workarounds would apply here.  Maybe have users create world writeable drop locations?

Comment: But there should be some way that user can login into his account using Putty to give me access right?

Comment: Yes, my point was that it's standard linux permissions.  So they can create a directory you can write to, make their home directory world writeable, etc, etc.   Using SCP is no different than having logged in via Putty and trying to copy the file on the command line - you still wouldn't have permissions to write to their home directory, and they'll have to create a directory you can write to.

Comment: If you have sudo power, you can copy the file across to your folder from anywhere within the system.